# Improve loading time of fragment transaction for android applications

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, usability

I'm currently developing an app ( you may have answered or saw some other questions of me ) and am having an usability problem. I have a navigation drawer and when the user clicks on one of the items another fragment replaces the main frame_content. The problem I'm encountering is that, the transaction takes some time on my devie.

I click on one item in the navigation drawer, then the app "stucks" for some seconds and will continue working fine.

I also know where the problem is, because, when I'm replacing a fragment that has no data in it it works instantly. It's just, that the app has to display really much data. I'm passing a `HashMap<String, Collection<String>>` to the fragment and am reading it out there. I'm saving it into an array and then I'm reading that array out again in a for loop and displaying the data.

I thought about various other ways like: reading all the data out in the main activity and then pass multiple arrays to the fragment. but the problem is, that i need 13 arrays for each fragment, because the hashmap contains data of 13 different keys. each key has 1 value. and there are 50 entries in total. So

50 Entries contain 13 keys contain 1 value.

This is pretty much data to load for the device. So I thought about how I could probably improve the speed of the loading fragment.

I'm downloading data from XML with AsyncTask while a splash screen is loading, then I'm saving it into different hashmap (depending on which xml i loaded). i then start a new intent to the main activity and pass all hash maps. then depending on the navigation drawer list a new fragment is opened and the hashmap is passed into a function in the fragment. then the data gets read into arrays and the array gets read out again in the OnCreateView method to add the data to the layout.

Any speed improvements ideas? this is how I currently change my fragments

```
protected void onNavItemSelected(int id) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    switch ((int) id) {
    case 101:
        MainFragment.passList(hashMap);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment());
        ft.commit();
        break;
//further cases....
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe

```
ft.commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
break;
```

will help you to execute the transaction faster (be sure to call it on main thread)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions()

Or if the problem is not in the transaction itself, maybe it is your loop that need improvment ?

Comment: I guess it's my loop. Since when I only have one item in the for loop it loads nearly instatnly. when i only have 5 it loads fast too, but when i have 50 (which i need) it takes too long. or should i just add 3 and when the user scrolls down autoload the next data?

Comment: I have a LinearLayout in a ScrollView in a RelativeLayout. Have the LinearLayout in the ScrollView because it can only have one child. Would you suggest to use a list view instead of a linear layout?

Comment: Maybe it will be better with a listView, but i'm not sure. You can try and check if it improves something or not

Comment: Same speed issues. Would it be possible to load all the data in an async-task of another class and display it there? I mean, display it in an non-active class? If yes, I could create an asyncTask and then add all the data to the layout, so then, when it's opened up it doesn't need to add them because it's already done... How is this possible?